# Set and Get a column from a table with foreign key in Java using Mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I'm using Eclipse with Mysql Workbench. I made an application that can create new entries in mysql table but I have a problem.

I have 3 tables: animals(id_animal, name), medics(id_medic, name) and the last one appoinments(id_appoinment, date, id_animal, id_medic) (the id_animal and id_medic from appoinments are foreign keys and the values are taken from animals and medics tables).

To manage connection with datebase i'm using a dbUtil package with EntityManager persistence.

Here is my code:

```
DatabaseUtil dbUtil = new DatabaseUtil();
Appoinment appoinment = new Appoinment();
appoinment.setIdAppoinment(1);
String date = "2018-12-25"; // YYYY-MM-DD
java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(date);
appoinment.setDataProgramarii(sqlDate);

appoinment.setAnimal(1); // this line doesn't work
// here I want to set in appoinments table an animal id from animals table
appoinment.setMedicID(1); // this line doesn't work
// here I want to set in appoinments table an medic id from medics table

dbUtil.setUp();
dbUtil.startTransaction();
dbUtil.saveAppoinment(appoinment);
dbUtil.commitTransaction();
dbUtil.printAllAppoinmentsFromDB();
dbUtil.closeEntityManager();
```

How can I set the animalID and medicID in appoinment table if they are foreign keys? I already have some animals and medics added to my table so I need to use that id's.

I except this code set an id for animal also for medic from already created tables animals and medics, but says that can't convert int to animal and medic.

Comment: Define "doesn't work", precisely. What do you expect this code to do (and why), and what does it do instead?

Comment: @JBNizet done that.

Comment: No, you haven't. You've said what you want to do. But you didn' say what you expect this code to do (and why), i.e. what you think it should do, and **what it actually does instead**? Example: `System.out.println("hello");`. I expect this code to print "Goodbye". But what it does is that it prints "Hello".

Comment: I except this code set an id for animal also for medic from already created tables animals and medics, but says that can't convert int to animal and medic.

Comment: So, you're trying to compile that code, and you get a compilation error. Knowing that, and knowing what the compilation error is, is crucial to know what the problem is. So edit your question, tell that you have a compilation error, and post the exact and complete error you get. Now, regarding the error. You're calling a method that expects a Medic as argument. And you're passing an integer instead. That can't possibly work, and has nothing to do with persistence, jPA, or anything.

Comment: Since the method expects a Medic, you need to pass it a Medic. Get the Medic from the dataase, using its ID, and pass the Medic as argument to the method: `appoinment.setMedic(entityManager.getReference(Medic.class, 1));`. Note the name of the method: you're setting a Medic, not a MedicID. A Medic is an entity. A MedicID is the ID of this object, which is an Integer.